# PagingLibrary in Android

Tags: android, android-paging-library

We are showing Search users from Webservice with the help of the Paging library in android.

We hide Recylerview if searchtext's length is below 2 characters.

When we search Second user(second time) in a row at that time PagedListAdatpter showing the old list for a few seconds till we get new SearchUsers.

How can we clear the current searchlist?

Comment: add some code so we can suggest solution clearly

Comment: Rather than hiding the recycler view set the data to an empty list. You have not provided and code so cannot provide a coded solution.